# Why is it needed to declare an array as static when returning it from a function. (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, static

I already know that a **`static`** storage class allows a local variable to keep on existing on the duration of the program.

What I would like to know why it is needed to declare the `digits[3]` array as static. What happens if I don't declare it as static, other than a compiling error.

P.S. I am quite new in handling pointers or memory addresses in C++.

Although I have a bit of an idea on the stack memory allocation regarding scopes in C++.

```
int* getDigits(int input)
{
    const int TEN = 10;
    int toStore;
    int digits[3]; /* this array (static) */
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {   
        toStore = input % TEN;
        digits[i] = toStore;
        input = input / TEN;
    }
    return digits;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int* ptr;
    ptr = getDigits(123);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *( ptr+i ) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Post all code as text. Images of code are near useless. 2. Why do you think it needs to be static?

Comment: you should be using `std::vector` or `std::array`. If you dont declare it as `static` it will be gone when the function returns and the pointer you return is dangling (ie useless outside of the function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to an array which is local to the function.  If you declare it as `static`, it means the lifetime of the array extends until the end of the program, so the calling code can dereference the pointer returned from the function.  If you do not declare it as `static`, it is an "automatic" variable whose lifetime ends when the block (function body) ends, and therefore dereferencing a returned pointer to the data is undefined behavior.

In any case, neither of these things is a typical, correct solution.  For one thing, if the function is called twice, the second call may change data pointed to by the first result.  A more typical solution is to have the function return a pointer (perhaps `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`) to an array allocated dynamically using `new int[3]`.  Another solution is to have the function create and return a `std::array<int, 3>`, which is a proper class type which can be returned by value (only C-style arrays cannot be readily returned by value from a function).

Comment: Returning a pointer to a variable of automatic storage duration does not give undefined behaviour.   Any attempt to dereference the returned pointer (which is probably the most common thing that might happen in calling code) does though.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 points that the [`static`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean) keyword used on a local variable will influence: **lifetime** and **initialization** of a variable.

1.
If you would declare a variable **non static** in a function like:

```
int* getDigits(int input)
{
   int digits[3]; /* local variable that dies on return */
   ...
   return digits;
}
```

the array `digits` is **not initialized** and it's **lifetime** is limited to the inner of the function as it's on the **stack**. If you return from the function the lifetime of the object ends and the access via the returned pointer is **undefined**, this could and probably will end in a crash of the program.

2.
But if you declare the array **static** like:

```
int* getDigits(int input)
{
   static int digits[3]; /* local variable that survives return */
   ...
   return digits;
}
```

it will be **zero initialized** and it's **lifetime** will survive the end of the function because it's memory is in the **data segment** of the program not the stack segment. The pointer that you return will be point to valid memory.

---

The 1st solution will end in undefined behaviour and the 2nd solution is not optimal as a second call to the `getDigits()` function would change the static variable `digits` on wich may a pointer from the first call points to.

It would be better to allocate the memory dynamically with [`new int[3]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) or pass the array to be changed as parameter. Moreover there is the possibility to use [`std::array<int, 3>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/) or [`std::vector<int>(3)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) of C++ that would be copied by value. That all would result in new returned variables for several calls of the function.